# spring xml context util:map key is ignored and bean id used instead

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I am trying to create a map of String=>Object like so:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

<util:map id="things">
    <entry key="something">
        <ref bean="somethingBean"/>
    </entry>
</util:map>

<bean id="somethingBean" class="Something"></bean>
```

After injecting that into my java code, I get a map, but the key is set to "somethingBean" rather than "something". Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: does it behave the same when u use <entry key="something" value-ref="somethingBean"> ?

Comment: Also, you can try using regular map instead of util namespace map, since you are not defining map class anyway.

Comment: tried that, same output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Spring freaks out if you inject such a map in constructor like so:

```
@Inject
public MyClass(Map<String, Something> things){}
```

It works OK if you use resource annotation instead:

```
@Resource(name = "things")
private Map<String, Something> things;
```